# Protect apache2 server-status handler by password

Tags: apache-2.2, debian

In my apache2 server I access `/server-status` to check my current status of the web-server. I found that mods-available/status.conf contains the snippets that is responsible for showing status.

```
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost ip6-localhost
</Location>
```

My question is how can i make it available not only for localhost but also for remote host with authentication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To allow other hosts, you can just update line:

```
Allow from localhost ip6-localhost
```

to read:

```
Allow from localhost ip6-localhost 1.2.3.4 1.2.3
```

For the authentication part, you add a block like:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Files"
# (Following line optional)
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords
Require user rbowen
```

The `passwords` file need to be created using `htpasswd` utility. Have a look at [this page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html) for more details.

Comment: You can allow single IP like `1.2.3.4` or subnet like `1.2.3`.

Comment: Will it allow hackers to brute force attack on this page to get information?

Comment: @Shiplu: If an IP is not allowed, it will receive forbidden error.

Comment: I am from a B class network where I have 65k peers. And my IP is dynamic. So I will set the network not a fixed ip. In that case if any of my peer tries to brute force it what should I do?

Comment: @Shiplu: No, you are not "from a B class network" -- unless you're making requests from [September 1993](ftp://ftp.rfc-editor.org/in-notes/rfc1519.txt).

Comment: @Shiplu: If your information is really sensitive and you don't trust your network users, you can go https instead of plain http.

Comment: @womble I `B` class network so its more understandable. In fact I am talking about a network where network is 20 bit. My IP is `1.2.3.4/20`. Total maximum number of my peers are `4093`

Answer (score 4):

In the `<Location /server-status>` stanza, include both the `Allow from localhost` and authentication directives.  The key is to use [`Satisfy Any`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#satisfy) to specify that requests from localhost can bypass authentication.

***Edit:*** Explicit example, as requested (it just combines everything that everyone has said so far):

```
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Satisfy Any

    Allow from localhost ip6-localhost

    AuthType basic
    AuthName "Apache status"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwd-server-status
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Comment: Could you show an example?

Comment: Thanks. I was actually looking for a `Satisfy Any` directive example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something similar:

```
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    AuthType basic
    AuthName "Apache status"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwd-server-status
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Also, don't forget to create the password file and account for yourself with the following command (replace *username* with whatever username you prefer):

```
htpasswd -c /etc/apache2/passwd-server-status username
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the risk of apache having  the server status handlers configured  .I can see this file in my webserver 
    SetHandler server-status
    AuthType basic
    AuthName "Apache status"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwd-server-status
    Require valid-user

Comment: <Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost ip6-localhost
</Location>

Answer (score 0):

If your website loads instead of the status page, add `RewriteEngine Off` to `<Location>`. This sometimes happens if an `.htaccess` file is present.

Comment: The question was how to enable /server-status for other hosts while requiring authentication.

Comment: @AndrewSchulman This was an issue I ran into configuring mod_status for the first time yesterday. If there's a conflict with mod_rewrite, it's not going to work either locally or remotely. It is a relevant to the question being asked and I wish someone had written it here. It would have saved me an hour of troubleshooting.