# Command line only mod_status Alternative?

Tags: apache-2.2

I have an Apache httpd that is eating up memory.  We need to restart it every hour.  We are playing with the MaxRequestsPerChild and sutch...

But we don't know what effects these changes are doing.  mod_status seems to be what I want,  but I work in a high security area and mod_status is a non-starter

Is there a command line tool that I can use to diagnose Apache problems from the Sever only?

thanks

Comment: You can protect the mod_status URL with authorization.  For example see [Protect apache2 server-status handler by password](http://serverfault.com/questions/377783/protect-apache2-server-status-handler-by-password)

Answer (score 2):

Set up a virtual host for localhost only:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
  <Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

You can further protect this resource by setting up authorization, as suggested in the comments.

From the command line, you can query this using `curl` or `wget` and pretty-print the output with `elinks -dump` or something similar.